# Value error in Python f\x00o\x00r\x00t

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I am embedding Python into C++. I am sending a big amount of data from C++ to Python and then doing manipulations on the data in Python. In C++ the data is stored in the form of a 2-D vector of float which via Tuple I am sending to Python.

Now, I am not sure in what format the data is received in Python. Is it in str or utf-16 or utf-8(I dont even know what are the meanings of these things). My aim is to just receive the data as array over here in Python and apply some scikit-learn functions to it.

I am able to apply he numpy.array functions to it and convert the data which I just received in Python to numpy arrays. Now, when I am passing this array to the scikit functions it is giving me the error like u"Invalid mode, expected 'c' or 'fortran', got f\x00o\x00r\x00t" .

By looking at the different posts, I am pretty sure it has something to do with the way the data is read in Python i.e the format but the solution provided everywhere is dealing with reading files and they say whenever we open a file use utf-16 but in my scenario I dont have a file I have arguments in Python. So how do I read them in a proper format to pass them to the scikit functions?

```
Call from C++ :

pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgTuple);

Python side :

import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from FS_package.function.similarity_based import fisher_score
from FS_package.utility import construct_W
def main(*Z):
   aList = []   
   print "I was called with", len(Z), "arguments:"
   for i in range(len(Z) - 1):
       aList.append(Z[i])
   X1 = np.array(aList)
   X = X1.T
   y = np.array(Z[len(Z) - 1])
   n_samples, n_features = X.shape
   num_fea = 100
   neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
   for train, test in ss:
       selected_features = X[:, idx[0:num_fea]]
       neigh.fit(selected_features[train], y[train])
```

The neigh.fit is giving me the error.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you post the function call and the stacktrace? Also the function argument values (or at least part of them)? I have a hunch about the error, but i need to be sure before posting an official answer.

Comment: Create a minimal example demonstrating the problem, everything else is just guessing.

Comment: Looks like you have UTF-16 data; little endian, with the last `\x00` missing. Unless your data *starts* with `\x00`, in which case it is big endian.

Comment: actually just posted the relevant portion. The function is doing much more things.

Comment: Is this on Windows? If so, you are handling wide strings (UTF-16) here. `fortran` happens to be 7 characters, and your data is 7 bytes, but obviously truncated.

Comment: Nopes. this is red hat.

Comment: How about you show the C++ side of things are remove all the irrelevant parts of the Python side? An example still must be complete in order to allow any meaningful analysis.